# Hidden field in fields_for not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `fields_for` to build an associative table with my user table. Everything seems to work ok, except when it adds the record to the database it comes out as nil.

**erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_path(@user), :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'Name' %>
  <%= f.label :email%>
  <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.label :address%>
  <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Address" %>
  <%= f.label :phone %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone Number" %>
  <%= f.label :resume %>
  <%= f.file_field :resume %>
  <%= f.label :cover_letter %>
  <%= f.file_field :cover_letter %>

  <% f.fields_for @userjob do |ff| %>
    <% ff.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
    <% ff.hidden_field :job_id, :value => @jobs.first.id %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Apply"%>
<% end %>
```

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :userjob
    validates :name, presence: true
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    mount_uploader :resume, ResumeUploader
    mount_uploader :cover_letter, CoverLetterUploader
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :userjob
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.name = auth.info.name
          user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
          user.save!
        end
    end
end
```

**job controller**

```
def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    @user = User.new
    @userjob = UserJob.new
end
```

**user controller**

```
def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        @userjob = UserJob.new(user_params[userjob_attributes:[:user_id, :job_id]])
        if @user.save & @userjob.save
            flash[:success] = "Thanks for applying!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :address, :phone, :resume, :cover_letter, userjob_attributes:[:user_id, :job_id])
    end
end
```

**db**

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserJob id: 1, user_id: nil, job_id: nil
```

**log params**

```
parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HLT46ditBHYcnAgOfZ7nfdDIP90EjNUdB+QB+3vjJOqnva6ZzVMXh0OiQte2v34aQ7opK8gPuk63fCTUVkJfBw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"test7", "email"=>"test7@test.com", "address"=>"", "phone"=>""}, "commit"=>"Apply"}
```

Comment: why are you not having `=` sign with the `fields_for` and `hidden_field` tag. that is the reason i guess

Comment: Thx, tried this fix and still does not work.

Comment: please if you can share in question the `params` from the logs which you get on action that would be helpful.

Comment: you are not receiving `user_job` as hash in parameter at all that is why both `user_id` and `job_id` are nil. does your `@userjob` exists.?

Comment: show us your new action

Comment: @leo updated, the form action is on an index page

Comment: replace your line `<% f.fields_for @userjob do |ff| %>` with this one `<%= f.fields_for @user.user_jobs.build do |ff| %>` and try please.

Comment: i have updated your index action

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method user_jobs' for #<User:0x007f998aa68170>`

Comment: sorry i think you are using `userjob` instead of `user_job` which is not good but still try this `<%= f.fields_for @user.userjobs.build do |ff| %>`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing works. Must've really screwed this up.

Comment: u need to reveal your user model too then

Comment: make it `has_many :user_jobs`, and what is in your user table, user_job_id?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "<%=", they are hidden fields but must be "painted".

```
<%= f.fields_for @userjob do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :job_id, :value => @jobs.first.id %>
<% end %>
```